# why doesn't liquid metal vaporize in a vacuum?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, condensed-matter, pressure, temperature

I am wondering why molten metal in a vacuum of electron beam and machines never turns to gas like liquid water does when exposed to a vacuum.

Comment: How does the pressure & temperature of the electron beam compare to the [boiling point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling_point) and/or [flash evaporation pont](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_evaporation) of the two?

Comment: Clearly enough is evaporating (turning into a gas) to be useful for depositing thin films.

Comment: It might has some dynamic effect. But, from the equilibrium point of view, possibly the vapor pressure at that temperature is very low?

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, the bonds between Iron molecules is much stronger than between water molecules.   Iron's sublimation temperature in a vacuum is (I couldn't find exactly), but around 500 degrees C on the chart (below).   At 1 ATM vaporization temp is much higher, a bit over 2,500 C.    It won't stay in vapor form unless the atmosphere is above a certain temperature/pressure threshold that we don't see very often.   I would imagine an electron beam could vaporize Iron, but it wouldn't stay vaporized very long.

Without an Electron beam, Iron would need to be in a hot vacuum to vaporize.   In our solar system, Iron would probobly have to be a little bit closer to the sun than Mercury to be at vaporization temperature.

Source, Wiki (I'm afraid).   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pure_iron_phase_diagram_%28EN%29.png